# Achievements / Достижения iOS, Google Play

Tags: android, ios, разработка-игр, google-play, google-play-services

Использую GMS. На самом деле у меня 3 вопроса:

1. При создании достижений в GP мы задаём кол-во очков которые получит игрок за выполнение каждого из них, а вот в iOS написано - "Необходимое количество очков" Это одно и то же? Просто косячный перевод? Вроде там и там нужно просто передать 100%
2. Если достижение можно получить только 1 раз но в игре событие получения достижения отсылается несколько раз косяков не будет?
3. Если учитывать, что игрок играл без интернета и получил скажем 15 достижений которые записались в файл. Теперь при подключении его к сервису достижений (GP, Game center) я передаю их туда используя цикл:

Пример хранения ачи:

```
mass_achi[0,0]="JHGdsfUWD75562348"
mass_achi[0,1]=1
mass_achi[0,2]="1000 Очков!"
```

Цикл:

```
for (i=0;i<=27;i++)
{
   if mass_achi[i,1]==1
   {
   отсылаю достижение[i,0] 
   }
}
```

Я переживаю за то, что если я их передаю как бы "очень быстро и много" все ли они достигнут конечной точки? Или стоит этот процесс как то притормозить и отсылать 1 достижение скажем раз в секунду или более? Извините за тупые вопросы.

Comment: дайте хоть ссылку на этот gms, и почему не game center на ios?

Comment: да вопрос не в GMS циклы везде одинаковые. GMS - https://www.yoyogames.com